# add text to nivo control nav thumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I am trying to add test into the controlNavThumb alongside the thumbnail and cant see to find an example. Here is my code so far.

Here is an example I am trying to replicate http://templates.eugeneo.com/network/

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        directionNav: false,
        controlNavThumbs: true, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel: true, // Use image rel for thumbs
    });
});

        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">         
            <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img title="#caption1" src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Curabitur dfgd" rel="images/slide1_thumb.jpg" /></a>             
            <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img title="#caption2" src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Curabitur" rel="images/slide2_thumb.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="nivo-html-caption" id="caption1">
                <span>Curabitur auctor, lectus in egestas pellentesque</span>
                This is caption 1 with <a href="single.html">a link</a>.
        </div>
        <div class="nivo-html-caption" id="caption2">
                <span>Curabitur auctor, lectus in egestas pellentesque</span>
                This is caption 1 with <a href="single.html">a link</a>.
        </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to add text to the control nav you'll need to make sure the text-indentation is set to a positive number. Then to add the text you may need to `append()`/`prepend()` it after the nivoSlider has loaded.

Comment: i will have different text for each image and I will be loading from the database. The link I provided seems to have code somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

of course you can add text check out this example - http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/3/

Comment: thanks, but I have looked at this this I see nothing that could help me in the code